# how to extract members of tar.gz file within a zip file in Python

Tags: python, zip, tarfile

zip file contains tar.gz file. How do I retrieve the members of the tar.gz file without extract to disk first?

```
abc.zip
  |- def.txt
  |- ghi.zip 
  |- jkl.tar.gz


def scan_zip_file(zfile):
    l_files = []
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as zf:
        for zname in zf.namelist(): 
            if zname.endswith('.zip'):
                with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(zf.read(zname))) as zf2:
                   l_files.extend(zf2.namelist())
            elif zname.endswith('.tar.gz'):
                pass
            else:
                l_files.append(zname)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted? How does its output differ from what you expect?

Comment: want to retrieve members from tar.gz as well... not only zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module, in a very similar way you used the zipfile module.
To complete your code and get the names of files in the tar.gz file:

```py
def scan_zip_file(zfile):
    l_files = []
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zfile, 'r') as zf:
        for zname in zf.namelist(): 
            if zname.endswith('.zip'):
                with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(zf.read(zname))) as zf2:
                   l_files.extend(zf2.namelist())
            elif zname.endswith('.tar.gz'):
                with tarfile.open(fileobj=io.BytesIO(zf.read(zname))) as tf:
                   l_files.extend(tf.getnames())
            else:
                l_files.append(zname)
```

The `fileobj` argument for `tarfile.open` tells it to use a 'File-like object' which io.BytesIO returns.

Comment: tarfile.open(io.BytesIO(zf.read(zname))) gives exception: "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO"

Comment: @fivelements You forgot the fileobj parameter

Comment: Edited the answer to add info about fileobj